# how open a pdf file from assents in an xamarin Android forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to open a PDF file from **assents** folder to **activity** in Xamarin Android

Comment: i try all this solusion :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176549/open-pdf-file-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: i want to open  file finished.pdf  from assents

Comment: okey , I will send to you the project link at my github and please help me .

Answer (score 0):

in **MainActivity.cs**

**using Com.Joanzapata.Pdfview;
using Com.Joanzapata.Pdfview.Listener;**

namespace openpdf
{
    [Activity(Label = "openpdf", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

```
    PDFView pdf;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        **pdf = FindViewById<PDFView>(Resource.Id.pDFView1);
        pdf.FromAsset("finished.pdf").Load();**
    }
}
```

}

Main.Axml

```
<com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="548.5dp"
    android:id="@+id/pDFView1" />
```