# Xamarin.forms Device.OpenUri can't open https://xxx.PDF file in Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I try to open a PDF file in WebView by using `Device.OpenUri(newUri(args.Url));`. 
This function is show open failed message when this PDF URL use https but not http.

This function is work in IOS platform. The android platform still work but only when URL is http://xxx.xxx.PDF. If the URL is just web page is work whatever is http or https.

```
public void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Url.StartsWith("file://"))
    {
        return;
    }
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));

    args.Cancel = true;
}
```

This app wouldn't crash when open https://xxx.xxx.PDF but just show messsage can't open this PDF. I try to open in PC is work and IOS is also work too.

Comment: Android doesn't have built in support for viewing PDF.  iOS does.

Comment: I confirm I can open in http URL in Android6.0 API 23 or download a PDF file in Android 24 API 24

Comment: do those devices have a PDF app installed?

Comment: Android 24 API 24 have Adobe Acrobat Reader

Comment: You can try the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176549/open-pdf-file-in-xamarin-forms/41180688) thread to open a pdf file by using `Device.OpenUri`.

Comment: But my PDF link is in web. This WebView first page is like list to choice one Uri. So I can't send first Uri in  XAML. `<local:CustomFormsWebView x:Name="wvInfo" Navigating="WebView_Navigating">`